# Binding together tables using GROUP BY with columns about category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a problem with handle aggregate columns in SQL Server 2014 version which does not support `GROUP_CONCAT` function. My task is to create query which bind together a few tables by its common columns, so suppose there will be two example tables.

Table A (Category 1)

```
| name | size |
+------+------+
| aaa  | 2    |
| bbb  | 3    |
```

Table B (Category 2)

```
| name | size |
+------+------+
| aaa  | 2    |
| ccc  | 7    |
```

Please notice that first records on both tables are the same.

I want to get following results:

```
| name | size | category_id | secondary_category_id |
+------+------+-------------+-----------------------+
| aaa  | 2    | 1           | 2                     |
| bbb  | 3    | 1           | NULL                  |
| ccc  | 7    | 2           | NULL                  |
```

The `category_id` column is always filled by ID which is hardcoded for each table, for example:

```
SELECT name, size, '1' AS category_id 
FROM Table_A 
GROUP BY name, size

UNION ALL

SELECT name, size, '2' AS category_id 
FROM Table_B 
GROUP BY name, size
```

But some entries in tables may be duplicated and for those row I want fill `secondary_column_id` with value identifying table (in this case 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(c1.name, c2.name) as name,
       coalesce(c1.size, c2.size) as size,
       (case when c1.name is not null then 1 else 2 end) as category_id,
       (case when c1.name is not null and c2.name is not null then 2 end) as secondary_category_id
from category1 c1 full join
     category2 c2
     on c1.name = c2.name and c1.size = c2.size
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not work for me. Maybe this is why I have to many columns on each tables which are used on select statement. Also I going to merge 4 tables so I think I will need generic solution.

Comment: @MarcinKozak . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  If you have a different question -- such as about 4 tables -- I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.

Comment: I spent some time on improve my query structure to your solution and it works. Thanks :)